How to transform a linestring geometry type to a SpatialPolygon
I am having troubles to transform a coastline of the east Atlantic area (west coast of Africa) into a SpatialPolygon to worh with it later. The problem is that when I transform it into a SpatialPolygon a line that merges the north of africa with the south is inclined and crosses the map as you can see in the picture I attached. One of the issues I think that can be causing this problem is the UTM tranformation maybe. I am working with several areas including the north and the south hemisphere, so may be this can be influencing the final product?The idea behing is to used for the creation of a mesh with R-INLA in order to project some sampling points in the ocean.
African west coast
library(sp)
library(sf)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(rnaturalearthdata)
library(FRK)

coastline <- ne_download(scale = "medium", type = "coastline", category = "physical", returnclass = "sf") #Download the data
bbox_west_africa <- st_bbox(c(xmin = -43.18, xmax = 19.34, ymin = -26.57, ymax = 29.49), crs = st_crs(coastline)) #to crop the data later

coastline_west_africa <- st_crop(coastline, bbox_west_africa) #The study area I need

coordinates <- st_coordinates(coastline) #Extract the coordinates to transform it

coordinates_df <- as.data.frame(coordinates) #Transform it to a Data.Frame


AfricanPolygon <- df_to_SpatialPolygons(coordinates_df,"L1",c("X","Y"), proj = CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=sphere")) #tranform a data.frame to a SpatialPolygon
AfricanPolygon
plot(AfricanPolygon)


AfricanPolygon
class       : SpatialPolygons
features    : 34
extent      : -43.18, 15.39318, -27.46624, 33.43104  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs         : +proj=longlat +ellps=sphere +no_defs

Not familiar with R-INLA, but does your data need to be SpatialPolygons instead of SpatialLines? For instance, sf::as_Spatial(coastline_west_africa) creates a SpatialLinesDataFrame compatible with sp. I think the "merging" is caused by coercing your coordinates into a polygon, so the first and last coordinates are interpreted as vertices that need to be connected to form a closed polygon. For instance, the same "merged" result occurs if you run sf::st_cast(coastline_west_africa, to = "POLYGON") |> plot().

Hi! Thank you so much for your answer. INLA works with SpatialPolygons so it should be converted in that format. I think it its what you have mentions, R do not understand that the polygon should be closed by creating a rectangle, so it merges the last coordinates. However, I do not know how to solve this. Any ideas?

You are cutting a line from a set of lines and then trying to make a polygon - so sf joins the ends of the lines.
Get a polygon of Africa and crop that instead. Either find one online or build it by dissolving African countries from Natural Earth.
mapunits = ne_download(scale = "medium", type = "map_units", returnclass = "sf") 
africa = mapunits[mapunits$CONTINENT=="Africa",]
sf_use_s2(FALSE) # pretend lat-long is cartesian
coast = st_crop(st_union(africa), bbox_west_africa)
plot(coast)


You've got a bit of South America in your image, which I assume you don't want.
Note the use of sf_use_s2(FALSE) so sf doesn't use spherical geometry, in which bounding boxes aren't boxes. If you want to transform everything to UTM and work in that, do that.

Thank you so much!!!! It has worked perfectly :)
